# How to disallow git commit when debug code is present

Tags: c++, git

I have some debug code that I want to make sure that I don't commit to Git.

Something like:

```
void myImportantFunction () {
    while (true) {
       //MyCode
#ifndef NDEBUG
       //TODO remove before commit
       std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));  
#endif
    }
}
```

The ifndef NDEBUG will protect me from this making it accidentally to production but I will still upset my colleagues by making the debug version run really slowly.

Is there a way that I can set-up GIT to not accept this code on a commit. I would prefer not to do it on TODO because there might be other instances of it but I would be happy to add another tag is that is possible.

Comment: Alternative suggestion: use `git add -up` when staging changes so you can manually approve each change.

Comment: instead of NDEBUG use some other PAULB_DEBUG_CODE define which you can define/undefine in the makefile or project setting and add this file to your personal gitignore. So even if the code is committed - it will never affect other programmer since they will not have it defined. And all such codes will be easy to find since it will be your dedicated name

Comment: looks like a job for a client-hook involving `grep`, no?
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: You *could* use a `pre-commit` hook to implement whatever checking you want prior to accepting a commit.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pre-commit hook I use :

It scans all files staged for commit for a special word : `dontcommit` ; if this word is present somewhere, the commit command fails.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
                                                                            
# check if 'dontcommit' tag is present in files staged for commit
function dontcommit_tag () {                                                    
    git grep --cached -n -i "dontcommit" -- $(git diff --cached --name-only)                            
}                                                                               

# if 'dontcommit' tag is present, exit with error code                                                                        
if dontcommit_tag                                                               
then                                                                            
    echo "*** Found 'DONTCOMMIT' flag in staged files, commit refused"          
    exit 1                                                                      
fi
```

Whenever I add a block of code for debugging, which I intend to remove before committing, I type an extra `// dontcommit` comment :

```
void myImportantFunction () {
    while (true) {
       //MyCode
#ifndef NDEBUG
       // dontcommit
       std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));  
#endif
    }
}
```

It's not foolproof, but it works for me.

Comment: You can use `git grep --cached "dontcommit" $(git diff --cached --name-only)` in order to scan only newly staged files

Comment: updated the code with @namero999's suggestion